# having trouble adding reset button to verilog code

Tags: verilog, fpga, xilinx

I have a top module that implements a 14-bit counter.

I added an input button in the top module and to the 14-bit counter

In the counter I check to see if the button is pressed and if so reset the counter to 0.

I have also added the line

NET "button" LOC = K18;

to the .ucf file.

But the design will not implement.  It complains that button is defined but not used and something about button_ibuf and button has no load...

does anyone have an idea what is wrong with my code?

here is the counter module

```
module counter_14bit(
input wire counter_clk_signal,
input wire switch,          // enable / disable the counter
input wire button,          // reset the counter to 0
output reg [13:0] counter=0     // 14 bit counter value (0-16383)
    );

always@(posedge counter_clk_signal)
begin   
    if (switch == 0) begin
        counter <= counter;
    end
    
    // max 14-bit unsigned value is 16383 but my board has only 4 sseg displays so
    // limit counter to 9999 max
    if (switch == 1) begin
        if (button == 1) begin
           counter <= 0;    // reset counter to 0 if button 1 is pressed
        end
        if (counter == 9999) begin  // reset counter to 0 if counter is 9999
            counter <= 0;
        end else begin
            counter <= counter+1;
        end
    end

end

endmodule
```

Comment: Is `counter_14bit` the top-level module, or where is it instantiated?

Comment: you should provide more information about error messages and the code around the counter_14b module.  *something about button_ibuf and button has no load..* is not very descriptive.

Answer (score -1):

You must remember that in the Verilog the non-blocking assignments are not executed sequentially, but all executed simultaneously. All the effects of all assignments will be applied at the end of the `always` block, and if there are multiple assignments to the same register - the last assignment wins.

You have `counter` assigned multiple times, once after checking the `button` input, and then by result of checking the counter against 9999. That second section overrides anything done on counter prior that manipulation.

Move the `if (button)` section below the section that counts up or wraps the counter around 9999.

Comment: actually, it can be solved by adding 'else' after the button's 'if'. or 'if (button == 1 || conter == 9999)' will also work.